# SJCL.js equivalent for ObjC

Tags: objective-c, macos, aes, sjcl

I am developing a client app for a RESTful web service. The web app uses the Stanford JS Crypto library for some client site cryptography and I would need to do that with the app too.

But the SJCL library doesn't just AES256 crypt the data, it does provide a kind of easy to wrapper around it. Have a look at the SJCL short overview page for more details: http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Does anybody has experience in providing a compatible process to crypt data like SJCL would do with ObjC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X and iOS both come with several frameworks which provide everything you need to do the same as SJCL: `CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h` and `Security/Security.h` to start with. From AES to PBKDF2, with SHA-1/2 or Base64 in between.

Comment: I know how to AES256 crypt something, but the RESTful API I need to use expect something exactly similar to the SJCL result of crypting data. Instead of the a key, SJCL just some random password as key, but I do not know how the password is linked with the AES key. Hoping on someone who has more detailed information about SJCL lib.

Comment: It's a pity, but reading the source is very hard too, because the developers used abbrevations for the variable names and I can only guess what they ment with 'p', 'j', 'rp', 'tmp' and so on. :(

Comment: You don't really have to dig in the sources. I mean, SHA-2 is SHA-2 whatever the implementation, as PBKDF2 is. Just use the proper algorithms with the save arguments and you'll get the same results. If you aren't sure, use some known test values to ensure you're doing it right.

Comment: The Stanford Cryptography I course is useful for learning the meta basics.  https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto